# Android: wait in each loop iteration until I return from an activity that is started inside each loop iteration

Tags: android, loops, wait

I have started to learn Android and I want to achieve the following: I have a loop and in each iteration I start an activity. I want to wait until I get back from that activity (that I start in each iteration) before doing the next loop iteration and start an activity again, and so on.

I have seen that I can obtain a result from an activity ( RESULT_OK if the activity worked properly):https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result , I guess I may have to use that functionality, but still I do not know how to wait until I get the  RESULT_OK from the activity (Maybe I am wrong and Idon't have to get the result from the started activity, as I said I am a beginner).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just start the first `Activity` with `startActivityForResult` and then when you return in `onActivityResult`, take next item in the list and `startActivityForResult`, rinse repeat?
The previous `Activity` where you've started your for-loop will be paused when a new `Activity` is started and so if you really want to use a for-loop, you need to store the state of the for-loop (the state in this case could be the index of what item you're iterating over). Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks